# Select rows from table using conditions across multiple rows in left joined table

Tags: mysql

I have 3 (or more) tables as follows in MySQL

persons

| id | name | gender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | nim | male |
| 2 | nam | female |

visits

| id | person_id | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2020-12-10 |
| 2 | 1 | 2020-12-16 |
| 3 | 1 | 2020-12-17 |
| 4 | 2 | 2020-12-20 |
| 5 | 2 | 2020-12-21 |

selected_options

| id | visit_id | option_a | option_b | option_c | option_d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | yes | no | yes | yes |
| 2 | 2 | no | no | no | no |
| 3 | 3 | yes | yes | no | no |
| 4 | 4 | yes | yes | yes | yes |
| 5 | 5 | yes | no | yes | yes |

Given the above table structure, I am looking to write a query that selects people who have selected "yes" to a set of options at during their visits.

E.g If the options to be queried are option_a = 'yes', option_b = 'no', option_c = 'no'; The query should return person with id 1 since he selected option_a as 'yes' at visit 1, option_b as 'no' in visits 1 and 2 and option_c as 'no' in visits 2 and 3. It should not return person 2 because person 2 selected option_a as 'yes' in visit 4, option_b as 'no' in visit 5 but never selected option c as no in any of their visits.

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  persons
    LEFT JOIN  visits  ON person.id = visit.person_id
    LEFT JOIN  selected_options  ON visit.id = selected_options.visit_id
    WHERE  (option_a, option_b, option_c) IN (('yes', 'no', 'no'))
```

However it does not match any values.

Comment: which mysql version are you using?

Comment: Also yuse a stored procedure, as you need to run all columns to see,if the pattern fits

Comment: I think you should consider revising your schema; a database table is NOT a spreadsheet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have to check every single column for validity, you can use such a construct.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE persons
>     (`id` int, `name` varchar(3), `gender` varchar(6))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO persons
>     (`id`, `name`, `gender`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 'nim', 'male'),
>     (2, 'nam', 'female')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE visits
>     (`id` int, `person_id` int, `date` varchar(10))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO visits
>     (`id`, `person_id`, `date`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 1, '2020-12-10'),
>     (2, 1, '2020-12-16'),
>     (3, 1, '2020-12-17'),
>     (4, 2, '2020-12-20'),
>     (5, 2, '2020-12-21')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE selected_options
>     (`id` int, `visit_id` int, `option_a` varchar(3), `option_b` varchar(3), `option_c` varchar(3), `option_d` varchar(3))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO selected_options
>     (`id`, `visit_id`, `option_a`, `option_b`, `option_c`, `option_d`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 1, 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'yes'),
>     (2, 2, 'no', 'no', 'no', 'no'),
>     (3, 3, 'yes', 'yes', 'no', 'no'),
>     (4, 4, 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes'),
>     (5, 5, 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'yes')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT *FROm persons p 
> WHERe EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM visits v INNER JOIN selected_options s ON v.`id` = s.`visit_id`
>              WHERE v.`person_id` = p.`id` AND s.`option_a` = 'yes')
> AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM visits v INNER JOIN selected_options s ON v.`id` = s.`visit_id`
>              WHERE v.`person_id` = p.`id` AND s.`option_b` = 'no')
> AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM visits v INNER JOIN selected_options s ON v.`id` = s.`visit_id`
>              WHERE v.`person_id` = p.`id` AND s.`option_c` = 'no')
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name | gender
> -: | :--- | :-----
>  1 | nim  | male
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=8848717c9d3eedd5e7612387ca16a003)*

Comment: Thanks for this. As I have to check every single column, I can assume that this may not scale so well right?

Comment: you have to add a EXISTS for every option you want to check, that are your conditions, but a index on visits an select_options should help with the performance

Comment: This solves my question. The jury is still out on performance. Thanks @nbk. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

**Another approach (Bits and Booleans)**

If the "options" are exactly yes/no (not "unknown" or "maybe"), then you could use a "bit" and put those bits into a `SET` or `INT`.  This would lead to a much more compact dataset, though the `WHERE` code would be messier.

`INT` would allow Boolean operations with which you could compute things that you seem to need:

- OptionA was "yes" for *any* visit by person-1.
- OptionA was "yes" for *all* visits by person-1.

`options BIGINT UNSIGNED` lets you handle 64 options, no more.  You could (with added complexity) use more than one column if you need more than 64 options.

The gist of the code is to `GROUP BY person` and do `BIT_AND(options)` to combine every column in order to test for "yes" at all visits.  `BIT_OR` would give you `yes` at *any* visit.  Other expressions would handle any/all "no".

Masking would let you select the, say, 3 options that the query is interested in.

To find visits with a particular set of yes/no values, just masking and equality suffices.  So `(option_a, option_b, option_c) IN (('yes', 'no', 'no'))` maps to (assuming a is bit 0, b is bit 1, etc):

```
WHERE options
    & ((1<<0) | (1<<1) | (1<<2))  -- check bits 0,1,2
    =  (1<<0)                     -- for 0 being YES; the rest being NO
```

Back to what might be the desired query:

```
WHERE BIT_OR(options) & (1<<0)  -- option_a is YES for _any_ visit
  AND BIT_AND(options) & (1<<1) = 0  -- b was NO for _any_ visit
  AND BIT_AND(options) & (1<<2) = 0  -- c was NO for _any_ visit
```

**Tips**

`LEFT` seems to be 'wrong', use a regular `JOIN`.

"Row constructors", in the past (pre 5.7.3), were quite inefficient.  Rewrite the `WHERE` if you are running an old version.

Please qualify column names so we know which table(s) they are in.

You show 4 options now.  Might there be 5 tomorrow?  And 6 the day after?  This leads to a maintenance question for the schema.